# Recognition of same Sex civil partnership In Czech Republic for non EU and EU spouses

Tags: visa, residency, marriage

Dears, I wanted to check something with you. 
Curently I live in Czech Republic. 
I am a citizen of Poland and in a relationship with a Brazilian same sex partner.  We plan to get married in oncoming months in Denmark. My partner would be on a touristic visa (which apparently is sufficient for marriage there). Therefore, once we are officially married, can he stay with me in Czech Republic? Meaning would he be granted residency visa based on our marriage certificate obtained in Denmark.  As far as I understand our marriage would work in CR as a civil partnership which would be sufficient for him to get residency if I were a Czech citizen. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As your spouse, your partner will qualify as your "family member" for the purpose of the [free movement directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616).  He should therefore be able to apply for a "residence card" under the directive to reside with you in the Czech Republic.

Your Danish marriage certificate should suffice to prove your relationship, but I do not know whether you will be required to furnish a certified translation.  Most countries require this.

Comment: Within the EU, you can request an international marriage certificate that follows a standard form and includes translations to the main EU languages.

Answer (score 1):

Quite recently there was a big decision reached about this in Romania, here is the relevant NY TIMES article. Hopefully the wave will spread quickly.
https://www.nytimes.com/2018/06/05/world/europe/romania-ecj-gay-marriage.html

Comment: Thanks for adding that.  I wanted to mention it but didn't have time to look it up.